# Имя пользователя в чате java ServerSocket

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, chat

Пишу многопоточное, клиент-серверное приложение (чат) на java с помощью ServerSocket. Необходимо чтобы сервер запоминал имя пользователя и при выходи из чата писал имя клиента, например: "Have a good day, Alex".

Я думаю, поскольку каждый новый поток это новый клиент, может каким-то образом присваивать имя пользователя к его потоку.
Подскажите, как это лучше сделать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В jvm, например, есть `ThreadLocal`.

Но зашиваться на такие вещи кажется не очень.
Вот захочется оптимизировать, чтоб потоков было меньше, чем клиентов.
Или будете промисы использовать, а они в другом потоке выполняются.